# R obtaining NaN values for properties in Spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire

So I already fixed the issue but I want to understand why it fixed it. Before when I tried to use R to obtain a certain Column property in spotfire it would always appeared to return a NaN value. Why does adding this line before calling the property resolve this issue?

`names( attributes( dt[ ,col] )$SpotfireColumnMetaData ) <- lapply( names( attributes( dt[ ,col] )$SpotfireColumnMetaData ), tolower )`

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure why you did what you did. Can you share `dput(head(dt))` before running the above line, show what was the issue you were facing and how running the above line fixed it.

Comment: @RonakShah here is an example of the output  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), it appears to be giving me the first few rows for each column. Where each column is contained in the c(). That specific column was empty, so I wasnt surprised.

Comment: I don't think this much of information is enough to help. See how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).